# Problem with mouse pointer/arrow keys in 14.04

Tags: mouse

Recently I updated my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.

My mouse doesn't work properly; if I just click or select an folder with the help of arrow keys , the screen automatically returns to desktop screen and right click also doesn't work for me. However, right clicking works in web screen when I am browsing net in Firefox.

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: i am using dell inspron 15 R 5521 Intel® Core™ i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4

Comment: no capslock key is good

Comment: now it is good... please don't use all caps in areas in you post.